# Using Getstream-js v3.0.0 with Parse Cloud

Tags: getstream-io

I am trying to use the Getstream-js v3.0.0 client with Parse Cloud, but when I replace `cloud/getstream.js` with the distributable file from `stream-js` I get the following error:

`Upgrade XMLHttpRequest is not found Stream.io`

Comment: Could you please elaborate? e.g. supply most relevant lines of error message, versions of integration libraries used.

Comment: On Parse cloud code add library of getStream.js https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GetStream/stream-js/parse/dist/js/getstream.js , Try to upgrade getStream latest https://github.com/GetStream/stream-js/blob/master/dist/js/getstream.js try to upload to parse cloud code

Comment: The Parse getstream javascript client is not interchangeable with the normal javascript client, since the Parse javascript api differs from default Javascript api.

Comment: @Matthisk Hi GetStream team,

         We are building an application where we need to have an aspect of feeds. And we are using getstream.io for the same.


We want to start using the latest library that was announced at:

http://blog.getstream.io/post/132088966648/stream-javascriptnode-client-v3


We are using Parse and want to start using the "copy limit" feature.

But, I cannot find an updated getstream.js file that I can deploy to Parse Cloud code.



All the application code that we have written today is based on the example at:

https://github.com/GetStream/Stream-Example-Parse


and al

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the Parse Cloud Getstream JavaScript client and the `stream-js` client are not interchangeable. Parse Cloud has different api's for several things (e.g. Http requests), that is why your attempt to replace the JavaScript file fails.

Hopefully we will release a new version of the Parse Cloud javascript client in the near future.